# What is meant by "anchor element" in Angular?

Tags: angular

I was reading the Angular docs and came across [this](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef#properties):

> elementRef: The anchor element in the parent view for this embedded view.

I also found this concept being used [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef#properties):

> location: The host or anchor element for this component instance.